# How to change html href attribute value with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change html href attribute value ?post=55 to ?post=44 with button click using jQuery, but don't know how.

**HTML**

```
<button class="button">button</button>

<a href="posts.php?post=55" class="post-link">Post</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {

  
});
```

**This is what I have**

```
<a href="posts.php?post=55" class="post-link">Post</a>
```

**This is what I want when clicking button**

```
<a href="posts.php?post=44" class="post-link">Post</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

A  Jquery function allows you to change an attribute of a tag. It is written as `$("tag").attr('attr','newvalue')`.
In your case, you can do `$("a").attr('href','posts.php?post=44')` inside the click function (you should probably give the a tag an id too)

Comment: jQuery provided 'attr()' function to modify HTML attributes,
`
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".button").click(function(){
         $("#Id_Of_Your_Button").attr("href", "newURL");
      });
   });`

Answer (score 0):

"on-click" handler has `$(this)` that you can use to navigate in the DOM tree if you know that the object you want to alter is relatively placed (from what I see you have `<a/>` following `<button/>`.

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.post-link').attr('href', '#hello-world')
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btof6sca/)

If you want to change a link of the element that is somewhere on the page, I would suggest searching by `id` value (the id should be unique). Let's say you have `<a id="my-id" href="...">...</a>`, then:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('#my-id').attr('href', '#hello-world')
})
```